# Field 'id' doesn't have a default value Hibernate SQL

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate

```
public class Coal {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String brand;
    @Column(name = "cube_size")
    private double cubeSize;
    private String country;
    private double price;
```

Addition new coal via controller

```
public static final String ALL_COALS = "/coals";
 @PostMapping(ALL_COALS + "/add")
    public Coal addCoal(@RequestBody Coal coal) {
       return coalService.addCoal(coal);
    }
```

Flyway migration script for this table

```
(
    id bigint not null auto_increment,
    brand     varchar(255),
    cube_size double,
    country   varchar(255),
    price     double,
    primary key (id)
);
```

And when I try to send POST request with Insomnia `http://localhost:8080/coals/add` with JSON

```
{
    "brand": "Loop",
    "cubeSize": 2.4,
    "country": "Russia",
    "price": 54
}
```

I receive the error `Field 'id' doesn't have a default value`.

I tried to insert JSON with id as well but no changes.

I saw some solutions but I have already added auto_increment to my migration like many people advised.

Update:

```
    @Service
    public Coal addCoal(Coal coal) {
        return coalRepository.save(coal);
    }
```

And Repo

```
    @Repository
public interface CoalRepository extends CrudRepository<Coal, Long> {
```

Comment: Please add your service method that's performing the save operation (`coalService.addCoal(coal);`)

Comment: @lane.maxwell I have it already. Service and repository. I've added it to the post.

Comment: There's some useful information that's missing from your question, like which DBMS you're using, the full set of annotations on your entities, etc.  Try modifying your flyway script to mark the id as the primary key.  `id bigint not null auto_increment primary key`